# Convenience method for writing just one byte

Tags: rust

I have a generic function that needs to write (non-ASCII) bytes to an `io::Write` writer.

The shortest way to reliably write a single byte provided by the `io::Write` trait is AFAIK `writer.write_all(&[0])?`. That is a bit long and syntactically noisy to write in many places.

Does Rust's stdlib have a macro or an extension trait with a convenience method that is shorter to write?

Comment: Do you _need_ to write bytewise? Under most file or network situations, that would be supremely slow? There are valid situations where you need to, however. Is this one of them?

Comment: `writer.write_all(&[0])` doesn't look that verbose (or at all verbose) to me. If you really think it's too verbose, you can create a utility function that does it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does Rust's stdlib have a macro or an extension trait with a convenience method that is shorter to write?

Not that I know of. But the nearly ubiquitous `byteorder` crate provides [`write_u8`](https://docs.rs/byteorder/1.1.0/byteorder/trait.WriteBytesExt.html#method.write_u8). Although it is unaffected by the machine's byte order, it was included for completeness.

```
use byteorder::WriteBytesExt;

writer.write_u8(0)?;
```

If you intend to use this method often, it might be a good idea to wrap the writer around a buffered writer such as [`BufWriter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufWriter.html).